# How do I undo several change lists in Perforce relating to the same files without submitting each one?

Tags: perforce, undo

I submitted a total of 6 change lists with progressing changes to several files. It was determined that all changes had to be reverted. I had to submit the undo change lists one by one. Now I want to undo the undo, so I can get back to the state I was in to fix the issue. P4V answers me with the following error message when I try to undo the 3'rd change list into the same single change list:

```
Undo operation cannot be performed
The following files are already checked out
... list of files that are already in the pending change list
```

How do I get around this? I know I can revert every single file to a specific version, but that is a tedious manual operation.

I am using "Helix Visual Client" version 2020.1/1946989.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are perhaps trying to undo by clicking on a submitted CL.

Instead you can click on a p4 depot path, and select undo, this will allow you to undo a range of change lists.

**Step 1**: Go to the common ancestors in path which has all the changed files

[image: Undo range of CL]

The dialog box which opens will allow you to specify a range of CL.

**Step 2**: In the undo dialog box select "Undo a range of changes ..." radio button. From the drop down which is now shown select `Changelist` instead of `Revision`.

[image: undo range of CL]

**Step 3**: Specify the first and last CL in the range to undo (both inclusive).

This has same effect as [Samwise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63563050/981766), but via p4v instead of command line.

More info: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4v/Content/P4V/files.undo.html

Answer (score 4):

Use the command line and "p4 undo" the range.  If the changes you want to undo are 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, and 106, do:

```
p4 undo @101,106
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I am surprised that the visual client doesn't have that feature built in.

Comment: How can you perform the same operation for several non-continuous changelists assuming you cannot do the operation in two steps in order to avoid checkout conflicts? e.g. 101, 102, 103, 106.

Comment: Do it in multiple steps (group it into contiguous ranges where possible, e.g. `p4 undo @101,103` -> `p4 undo @=106`) and use `p4 lock` to avoid conflicts with other clients.  If that's unacceptable, you can do weird things with `p4 shelve` and `p4 edit` to wedge it into one changelist, but I strongly recommend finding a way to accept doing it in multiple changelists.  :)

Comment: @4thex You can do the same with visual client as well, just added an answer for that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77177464/981766